# Why is the pronoun 'we' not changed to 'they' in this reported speech?

Tags: reported-speech

> > "Are we late?"
> >
> > Anna ______ late.
>
> A. asked we are
> B. said we were
> C. asked if we were

The answer should be C. To my understanding, the pronoun *we* should be changed to *they* in reported speech, but why not in this sentence?

Does this mean *we* includes Anna? Or are there any exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

*Anna asked if we were late* only makes sense if the person reporting the speech was one of the party. (C) is the only correct one of those three options, but *Anna asked if they were late* would also be a valid sentence if it was part of a story about Anna and her friends (not including the narrator).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the options is in the third person it indicates that the person reporting the speech  is a member of the group.

For example if Anna is Bill's wife and Anna and Bill were in a car travelling to a party Anna might say "Are we late?". If Bill reported the speech to Charles, the host of the party, he would say "Anna asked if we were late." because the plural pronoun "we" would stand for Anna and himself. If Charles then reported the speech to Diana, *his* wife, he would say "Anna asked if *they* were late" because the plural pronoun did not stand for a group including him.

Alternatively if Diana asked "Are Anna and Bill late?" Then Charles would report Diana's speech to Anna and Bill by saying "Diana asked if *you* were late because the pronoun "you" would stand for Anna and Bill who would be the second person plural from Charles's perspective.

The choice of pronoun depends on the context and the point of view of the person reporting the speech, not on whether the speech is direct or reported.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule that says "we" gets changed to "they" in reported speech. The use of pronouns is always based on the relationship between the speaker and the person/people/thing(s) being talked about.

"We" always includes (1) the speaker and (2) at least one other person.  The other person/people can be the person/people the speaker is talking to ("you") and/or other people who are not part of the conversation. In contrast, "they" does not include the speaker.  If someone says "they," the person is talking about multiple people/animals/things that do not include the speaker. **Reported speech does not change any of this.**

For example:

**Friend A and Friend B are talking:**

*Friend A: "What are you and your family going to do for Christmas?*"

*Friend B: "We are going to visit my grandmother in New York."*  **("we" = Friend B + Friend B's family)**

*Friend A: "That sounds nice. By the way, where should we go for lunch?"* **("we" = Friend A + Friend B)**

*Friend B: "We should try that new Italian restaurant, but we might have to wait for a table because it's popular."* **("we" = Friend A + Friend B)**

**After lunch:**

*Friend A: "You said that we might have to wait, but I didn't think it would take an hour!"* **("we" = Friend A + Friend B)**

**Person C and Person D hear Friend A and Friend B talking.**

*Person C talking to Person D: "Those guys said that they had to wait an hour for a table! Let's go somewhere else!"* **("They" = "Those guys" = Friend A + Friend B)**

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I clearly understand it now. :)